# SQL view table inner join 'and' statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im stuck in getting some data out of tables.

Project has multiple Products, but one is Primary (PrimaryProduct).

PrimaryProduct = Product.

Product is a part of Estimate.

Each Project is scheduled assigning to the Crew.

Basicly, the main table from where I could take crewid is tblProjectLabourSchedule and there ProjectEstimateID.

So i need to get Crew who is assigned to the Project but just for the Primary product. My query already brings out the Primary Product for the Project but im unable to get the Crew. My current script is bellow but now im getting all crews who are assigned to the Project (primary + secondary products):

Here are my tables:

```
                 tblProject:
                    ProjectID
                    PrimaryProductID

                tblProduct:
                    ProductID

                tblProjectEstimate:
                    ProjectEstimateID
                    ProjectID
                    EstimateID
                    CrewID

                tblProjectLabourSchedule:
                    ProjectLabourScheduleID
                    ProjectID
                    ProjectEstimateID << 
                    CrewLeaderID

                tblCrew:
                    CrewID
                    FirstName

                tblServiceTicket:
                    ServiceTicketID
                    ProjectID

                tblEstimateDetail:
                    EstimateDetailID
                    EstimateID
                    ActivityID
                    ProductID

                tblCrewLeaderMember:
                    CrewLeaderMemberID
                    CrewLeaderID
                    CrewID
```

Script:

```
SELECT    tblProjectLabourSchedule.CrewLeaderID

    FROM  tblServiceTicket INNER JOIN

        //gets primary product for the project

         tblProject on tblServiceTicket.ProjectID = tblProject.ProjectID inner join
         tblProduct on tblProject.PrimaryProductID = tblProduct.ProductID

        /// gets crews for the products

       tblProjectEstimate on tblServiceTicket.ProjectID = tblProjectEstimate.ProjectID inner join
       tblProjectLabourSchedule on tblProjectEstimate.ProjectEstimateID = tblProjectLabourSchedule.ProjectEstimateID
```

Comment: What is the difference between ProjectEstimateID and EstimateID in tblProjectEstimate?

Comment: The table you will need to connect the crew to the project, product and estimate is the tblEstimateDetail which is missing in your script. Join that table and you should be be able to get your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will give you crewID for just the Primary product.  You can join additional tables as necessary.

```
SELECT e.CrewID 
FROM tblProjectEstimate e 
INNER JOIN tblProject p ON p.ProjectID = e.ProjectID
INNER JOIN tblEstimateDetail d ON e.ProjectEstimateID = d.EstimateID AND d.ProductID = p.PrimaryProductID
```

UPDATE:
Using a left join with tblEstimateDetail will essentially list all project estimates regardless of primary product.

Can you try this? This will exclude any estimate detail where the primary product doesn't match up against the estimate project.

```
FROM  
tblServiceTicket s    
INNER JOIN tblProjectEstimate e on s.ProjectID = e.ProjectID  
left join tblProject as p ON p.ProjectID = e.ProjectID 
left join tblEstimateDetail as c ON e.ProjectEstimateID = c.EstimateID AND c.ProductID = p.PrimaryProductID
WHERE c.ProjectEstimateID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

@Bhaskar, here is the query that worked for me:

```
tblProjectEstimate as e on tblServiceTicket.ProjectID = e.ProjectID and e.IsPrimary = 'True' left join
tblCrew on e.CrewID = ptsweb.tblCrew.CrewID
```